# codeigniter pagination related questions

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = base_URL().'admin/issues/list_issues/';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('dt_issues')->num_rows();
$config['num_links']=10;
$config['per_page'] = 5;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

Codeigniter pagination was working properly. But when click on first link it is not working and the remaining links will work.  Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

$offset is the variable in which u can get value which page user is reqesting

```
function list_issues($offset = null)    
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
     ........
     // Pagination config
   $config['base_url'] = base_URL().'admin/issues/list_issues/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->provider_model->countprovider();
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    // $config['creat_link'] = 1; <-- This is not a valid option
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    // Init config
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    // If the pagination library doesn't recognize the current page add:
    $this->pagination->cur_page = $offset;

    .....
    // further your code
}
```

Comment: your missing some code, where is the num links, and the countprovider code is missing..